# Что ему не нравится?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сижу и не понимаю как исправить проблему

Comment: сдвиньте `print(...` вправо

Comment: Алгоритм на будущее: скопировать текст ошибки и вставить гугель. И не придётся сидеть и не понимать.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите последние 2 строки вашего кода:

```
for М in range (minmnog-1,maxmnog):
print( M,"x",a, "=",M*a)
```

Первая из них окончена двоеточием (`:`) - значит, что последующая строка нужна быть сдвигнута:

```
for М in range (minmnog-1,maxmnog):
    print( M,"x",a, "=",M*a)
```